# Jqgrid drop-down filter not updating after setting the filter values

Tags: javascript, filter, jqgrid

I have been working on a grid with provision for multiple dynamically populated filters (function getDropDownValues). The problem I have is that the column name being passed as a 'string' is not being found for the setColProp function. This is my code:

```
var lastsel2
    jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
        url: 'http://localhost:58404/JQGridHandler.ashx',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Property ID', 'Property Ref', 'Short Address', 'Scheme Code', 'Scheme Name', 'Property Type'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'PropertyID', index: 'PropertyID', width: 70, align: "left", stype: 'text', sortable: true},
            { name: 'PropertyRef', index: 'PropertyRef', width: 75, align: "left", stype: 'text', sortable: true},
            { name: 'ShortAddress', index: 'ShortAddress', width: 200,  align: "center", sortable: true},
            { name: 'SchemeCode', index: 'SchemeCode', width: 80, align: "center", sortable: true },
            { name: 'SchemeName', index: 'SchemeName', width: 80, align: "center",  sortable: true },
            { name: 'PropertyType',width: 80},
        ],
        beforeProcessing: function (data) {
            getDropDownValues(data, "PropertyType")
            $(this).jqGrid('destroyFilterToolbar').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
                stringResult: true,
                searchOnEnter: false,
                defaultSearch: "cn"
            });
         },
         onSelectRow: function(id){
             if(id && id!==lastsel2){
                jQuery('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2);
                jQuery('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
                lastsel2=id;
             }
         },
         rowNum: 30,
         editable: true,
         mtype: 'GET',
         loadonce: true,
         rowList: [30, 40, 50],
         pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
         sortname: 'PropertyId',            
         viewrecords: true,
         sortorder: 'desc',
         caption: "Property Details",
         editurl: 'http://localhost:58404/JQGridHandler.ashx'
     });

         function getDropDownValues(data, columnName) {
             var propertyMap = {}, propertyValues = ":All", rows = data, i, symbol;
             for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                symbol = rows[i][columnName];
                if (!propertyMap.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
                    propertyMap[symbol] = 1;
                    propertyValues += ";" + symbol + ":" + symbol;
                }
             }
            $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", 'columnName', {
                stype: "select",
                searchoptions: {
                    value: propertyValues
                }
            })
         }
```

Does anybody know how I can pass the column name so it can be located?

Comment: I have since discovered that the problem is with this line: $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", 'columnName', - If I state the column name explicitly 'PropertyType', it works. But if I pass it as a variable, it does not. The problem relates to (I assume) trying to find the column name as a string as opposed to an element.

Comment: If i dim columnName as var and then assign 'PropertyName' to it, the setCoProp works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is exactly in this line of code:

```
...
    $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", 'columnName',
...
```

but not the columnName parameter is the problem, but the way you cal the method setColProp.

The $(this) within jqGrid code in  most cases refer to the jqGrid object, but in case of external function as you do it referes to the function object and not to the grid and hence the code not work. To work you code, you should replace $(this) with jQuery("#jQGridDemo") i.e

```
function getDropDownValues(data, columnName) {
    var propertyMap = {}, propertyValues = ":All", rows = data, i, symbol;
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        symbol = rows[i][columnName];
        if (!propertyMap.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
            propertyMap[symbol] = 1;
            propertyValues += ";" + symbol + ":" + symbol;
        }
    }
    $(#jQGridDemo).jqGrid("setColProp", 'columnName', {
        stype: "select",
        searchoptions: {
            value: propertyValues
        }
    })
}
```

Tested the code with the new fix and it is working.

Comment: Excellent. Your explanation is much appreciated.